# Metal API View has no Render Pass Descriptor

Tags: swift, cocoa, metal

I am currently trying to build a metal app without the use of the IB in Xcode (purely programmatically, no storyboard), and I am having some trouble with rendering using MTKView Delegate.

I have created the following 3 classes

App Delegate:

```
import Cocoa
import MetalKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
    var newWindow: NSWindow?
    var controller: ViewController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(10, 10, 300, 300), styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .resizable, .titled], backing: .buffered, defer: false)

        controller = ViewController()
        let content = newWindow!.contentView! as NSView
        let view = controller!.view
        content.addSubview(view)
        newWindow!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

}
```

View Controller:

```
import Cocoa
import MetalKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var renderer: Renderer?

    override func loadView() {
        view = MTKView.init()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        guard let metalView = view as? MTKView else {
            fatalError("Cant Get Metal View")
        }

        super.viewDidLoad()

        renderer = Renderer(metalView: metalView)
    }
}
```

Renderer.swift:

```
import MetalKit

class Renderer: NSObject {

  static var device: MTLDevice!
  static var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue!
  var mesh: MTKMesh!
  var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer!
  var pipelineState: MTLRenderPipelineState!

  init(metalView: MTKView) {

    guard
      let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
      let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue() else {
        fatalError("GPU not available")
    }

    Renderer.device = device
    Renderer.commandQueue = commandQueue
    metalView.device = device

    let mdlMesh = Primative.makeCube(device: device, size: 1)

    do {
      mesh = try MTKMesh(mesh: mdlMesh, device: device)
    } catch let error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    vertexBuffer = mesh.vertexBuffers[0].buffer

    let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary()
    let vertexFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "vertex_main")
    let fragmentFunction = library?.makeFunction(name: "fragment_main")

    let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction
    pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction
    pipelineDescriptor.vertexDescriptor =
      MTKMetalVertexDescriptorFromModelIO(mdlMesh.vertexDescriptor)
    pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = metalView.colorPixelFormat
    do {
      pipelineState = try device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
    } catch let error {
      fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    super.init()
    metalView.clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0,
                                         blue: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)
    metalView.delegate = self
  }
}

extension Renderer: MTKViewDelegate {
  func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {

  }

  func draw(in view: MTKView) {
    // Creating Render Pass Descriptor
        if let descriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor
        {
            print("Drawing")
        }
        else {
            print("Not Drawing")
        }
    }
}
```

These three classes render the Window fine, and the output of

```
Not Drawing
```

Shows that this value is always null, but it is doing something every frame.

Things I have tried

- Creating My Own Render Pass Descriptor: This resulted in a sig error.
- Have checked the view, definitely being recognised a MTKView

I know this works if I use a project based on the storyboard in the file, but was hoping to learn how to do it without it.

Any Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317713/apple-metal-without-interface-builder)?

Comment: @trojanfoe I have yes, and have already overloaded both the load view and viewDidLoad, unless I am misunderstanding the article?

Comment: I think you are.  The point is that `viewDidLoad` is not being called when a NIB is not involved.  I don't know Swift but are you even calling the base class (`NSViewController`) `viewDidLoad` anyway?  I would stick to a storyboard and get on with your life.

Comment: @trojanfoe `loadView()` and `viewDidLoad()` are called from `let view = controller!.view`.

Comment: @Willeke and is the base class method called as well?

Comment: @trojanfoe `loadView()` "Instantiates a view from a nib file and sets the value of the view property.". This behaviour is replaced by the override. See [Creating a custom NSViewController without a nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845915/creating-a-custom-nsviewcontroller-without-a-nib)

Comment: @ThomasHeeley what is the frameSize of the view?

Comment: @Willeke Sorry I am new to this what would that be?

Comment: Do you set the `size` of the `frame` of the view somewhere?

Comment: @Willeke no I don’t

Comment: What is the size of the frame of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width and height of the view are `0`. Set the frame size before adding the view to the window in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

```
controller = ViewController()
let content = newWindow!.contentView! as NSView
let view = controller!.view
view.frame = content.bounds
content.addSubview(view)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs of `MTKView.currentRenderPassDescriptor`:

> This property is `nil` if the view’s `device` property isn’t set or if
>   `currentDrawable` is `nil`.

You need to give the `MTKView` a metal device to work with. IB is probably giving it  `MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()` by default, but when you create the view programmatically you need to do it manually:

```
override func loadView() {
    view = MTKView(frame: .zero, device: MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice())
}
```

Comment: I already set the default device in the renderer class? and then I set the view device in the renderer class as well

Comment: Ah, true. Have you checked if `view.device` is available in `draw(in view: MTKView)`?

Comment: Yep Im pretty sure its there. Its not nil when I check in `draw(in view: MTKView)`